# Limit select all to current page MUIDatatables

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am using mui-datatable in my application (https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables).
The "Select All" checkbox in header checks all the records in the table. How can i limit this to current page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have to create your own `customToolbar` and creating your own checkbox that performs some logic that make rows being selected. The number of rows being selected is dependent on the `rowsPerPage`.